# how to convert array in series to normal number in python

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, split, series

[[image: number of days - recency column]
[image]

I wish to extract the number of days only from the recency column

and i converted it to string and after split function extracted  first part a["recency"].str[:1]

But now the issue is I am unable to work on this series as its not accepted as int and not letting me convert it to a number series or any series as I am getting errors after splitting data.
error:

when I try to convert to int
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence  .

And if i try to map to int and use it at series   TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

some help would be great as I am still new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your data has no null values.

For removing null values you can use

`a.dropna(inplace=True)`

Assuming a is your dataframe

Now extract the first word from each row of recency column into elements variable

```
elements=a["recency"]
elements=[element.split(" ")[0] for element in elements]
```

Finally append all the numbers into the list

```
nums=[]
error_in_datas=[]
for x in range(len(elements)):
  if elements[x].isdigit():
    nums.append(int(elements[x]))
  else:
    error_in_datas.append(x)
print(nums)
print(error_in_datas)
```

nums is the list of your days and error_in_datas contains list of indexes that has no digits in the first place of your data as you wanted

Comment: Hi Dilip, thanks 
Also as it converts the series to list , would I be able to add it back to dataframe as I need the data to be added to the original dataframe after it extracts only the days from recency and replace it.
I am facing some issue and I assume its because the data is no longer a series.

Comment: you can make a new column let's say (Day) in dataframe and assign the list values from nums to the  new column. As the row errors in dataframes were already been deleted. all  the day values will automatically map to the respective row of previous dataframe